# How can I see who has access to my Google Drive folders?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I have a main folder in Google Drive with lots of sub folders that also have sub folders. The main folder is shared with my team. Some of the sub folders are shared with external people (temporary consultants for example). This has become a mess. I need to see a list of all people that have access to the sub folders so that I can delete the sharing. How can I do that?

I could go through all sub folders manual one by one but that would take forever.

Comment: I don't see any way to do it easily. There might be some tool available to a Google Apps admin, but I don't know what it might be.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Google apps and I'm the admin, any idea?

Comment: Not from me, sorry. I'm just a regular old Google Account user.

Comment: You can see the permitions for your google account at: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Answer (score 29):

If you know the email addresses of the people you have shared files with, all you have to do is enter the following search in Google Drive's search bar:

```
to: [email address]
```

Google Drive will then show all files shared with that user.

Comment: The `to:` search functionality was updated in March 2021 and a new `sharedwith:` operator was also added. https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/03/find-files-shared-with-you-using.html

Answer (score 19):

I know this answer is a bit late, but there is a new solution to this problem.

Check out https://whohasaccess.com to uncover all the people that access your shared files and folders.

[image]

***Disclaimer***: I'm part of the team that developed WhoHasAccess.

Comment: This is awesome, great work.

Comment: unfortunately the site is down.

Comment: @Arashsoft as far as I can see everything is running smoothly. Could you provide some details? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is relaed to my network, I am getting this error in chrome browser.

`This server requires a certificate for authentication, and didn't accept the one sent by the browser. Your certificate may have expired, or the server may not trust its issuer. You can try again with a different certificate, if you have one, or you may have to obtain a valid certificate from elsewhere.`

Comment: @Arashsoft I have tried it on a couple of browsers including Chrome on desktop and mobile, but no error yet. Also the certificate gets a pretty good grade on SSL tests: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=whohasaccess.com Would be great if you could provide some details on your setup to hi@whohasaccess.com

Comment: I tried with firefox and I get this error: `An error occurred during a connection to whohasaccess.com. Peer received a valid certificate, but access was denied. (Error code: ssl_error_access_denied_alert)`. I am sure there are some firewalls in my current network and maybe they are making problem for the connection. I will test it with a different network and will update it here.

Comment: Are you kidding me? It says "This will allow WhoHasAccess to:See, edit, create and delete all of your Google Drive files...."

Comment: @DouglasHeld In fact WhoHasAccess allows you to also revoke unnecessary access directly from the scan report, this is why manage (edit) permissions are included in the request scope. See https://www.whohasaccess.com/faq for more information.

Comment: This is a third party solution. Native solutions should be upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to find every file that had owners that were not myself as well, it was driving me crazy. Somehow there were a good amount of files and folders in there that I never remember having added at all. Not sure at all how that happened. Anyways, after playing around for a bit I found that if you search at the top, use:

```
-owner:me
```

That will show every file that has an owner other than yourself!

Comment: That is very interesting and helpful, but it not addressing the particular question.

Comment: So close to the perfect answer....  "-sharedwith:me"

Answer (score 3):

1. In the search bar at the top, enter `owner:me`
2. When all your files have loaded, click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the files
3. Right-click on any of the files and select *Share* to pop up a list of all the files
   you've shared with anyone
4. Scroll through the list, and click the checkbox next to any one you want to remove
5. Click *Done*

Comment: Looks promising! This is very, very slow but appears to work. If there are a lot of files, I think the approach might work best subdirectory-by-subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is currently no built in way to do this. As of now the only way is to do it manually by viewing the sharing options of the folder (As the GIF below depicts)

[image]

Comment: I wish this didn't keep replaying ad infinitum.

Comment: @aparente001 sorry, what?

Comment: This gif plays over and over and over again, ad nauseum.

Comment: @aparente001 of course it plays over and over. Otherwise you may not be able to see it originally before the first loop ended.

Comment: All I know is that it makes it hard to read the other materials on the page.  Perhaps I didn't understand your question when you asked, "Sorry, what?"

Answer (score 2):

I needed this so bad for my Google Apps account!

After a bit of searching, I found [**this post**](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-access/28237/) which uses a Google Script to scan all folders/files and sends you an email of all people who can access your Google Drive files.

Comment: Actually this is a very new script! Written in September 11, 2013.

Comment: Could you describe the contents of the link a little- that way, in the event that it moves, we don't lose all the info. Thanks!

Comment: This tool is 40$!

Answer (score -1):

I  do believe this is straight forward.

Put the view Owner Type and More,  you will then see the options on a float box of : Ownership and Visibility

.

I do believe they will allow you to find out what is shared and then remove people as you so desire.

However I am not sure if a list in the manner which you want is available using the default client tools.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you get to view owner type?

Comment: Alternatively if you are able to load on Flashpanel on to your GA account. I know it provides a documents exposure report in which this information is available.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Is the OP using a regular google account or a Google Apps one?

Comment: I'm using Google apps

Answer (score -3):

To get a list of shared folders you can perform a search of files with name 'desktop.ini', starting from root Google Drive folder.

Comment: It sounds like this will only work if you have synchronized your Google Drive with a Windows PC.

Answer (score -3):

This is how you can do it:

In the search bar in drive use "to:" to find documents you shared with someone.

Example:

```
to:bob@gmail.com
```

Comment: This solution was already offered in [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54081/354), and your answer doesn't appear to improve upon the solution.