# List shared items on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Is there a search command or a section where I can manage all my files and folders I shared? I know there is 'Shared with me' section but this only shows items from other people.

Comment: Not really. But see the workarounds in [How can I see who has access to my Google Drive folders?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46135).

Answer (score 1):

Try this service: http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-access/28237/

> The sharing details for files are not easily accessible in Google Drive but a Google script can scan your Google Drive and prepare a list of all files that have ever been shared from your Google Drive.