# Download list of addresses with access to a particular Google Drive file

Tags: google-drive, sharing, export

(This related thread did not answer my question: [How can I see who has access to my Google Drive folders?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46135/how-can-i-see-who-has-access-to-my-google-drive-folders).)

My son's school counselor has shared my son's weekly report with a gazillion irrelevant members of staff.  I would like to export (download) a list of the people who have access.

I know how to see the list, and I could make a series of screenshots -- but it would be nice to have something neater.