# Who has accessed a GDrive folder via link share?

Tags: file-sharing, google-drive

I share a folder in Google Drive via a **link share.** 
(the link is sent via e-mail)

Can I see a list of when the folder was accessed via this link?
Like a list with access times and maybe the IP addresses?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot see who accessed a public Google Drive folder. But if people are logged in it is possible via WhoHasAccess to list the users, who accessed the content.

Check out this link:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46135/how-can-i-see-who-has-access-to-my-google-drive-folders